# Going back to previous levels in an outline with jquery without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, back, outline

I’m fairly new to jQuery, so forgive me if I’m phrasing this incorrectly.

I’m trying to figure out the easiest way to move backwards through the following hierarchy.

The first page would show 3 topics like this:

Topic 1

Topic 2

Topic 3

When you click on each topic, it would lead you to 3 questions on that particular topic. (Example: You click on Topic 1 and all 3 topics are replaced by a new list that reads):

Question 1

Question 2

Question 3

I’ve gotten that much to work with the following code (repeated for each topic):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".topic_1").click(function(){
 $('div#questions_1').children().show();
$(".topic_1,.topic_2,.topic_3") .remove ();
$(this).unbind("click");
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".question_1_1").click(function(){
$(".question_1_2,.question_1_3") .hide ();
$(this).unbind("click");
});
})
```

What I can’t figure out how to do is to create a pseudo link that would appear when you click through to the 3 questions that when you clicked on it would take you back to having just the original 3 topics on the screen, without having to reload the page.

I'm hoping there's a way to write this so that it will be easy to add additional levels - each of which will have a back link to the previous level. If there were a way to have both forward and backward links, that would be even better.

I’m assuming there is some way to write this so that you’re toggling between the different objects, but can’t seem to get my brain around how to write it.

I’m also assuming that there’s a cleaner way to write the code I’m using, so any help on that end would be greatly appreciated, too.

Thanks in advance for any help you can be.

**Updated Question based on reply:**

I’m afraid I might not have explained what I’m after quite right.

When people click on any element, all of the other elements at that level are hidden and replaced replaced by just the siblings of the particular element that was clicked on.

So in your example, if I click on Topic 1, both Topic 1 & Topic 2 would be hidden, and “Foo,” “bar,” ; and “Up one level” would show.

And at the next level, when you click on Topic 1 and then click on foo, bar would also be hidden.

Finally, I noticed if I go from Topic to Foo to sub-foo, and then click on sub foo, that there are 2 “Up one level” links that appear under stuff? Is there a way to keep that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.remove()`ing your topics you could `hide()` them and then create a link/button in the questions area with a `click()` handler that `.show()`s the topics again.
Additionally:

1. There's no good reason for you to be unbinding the click handler; that only serves to make them not be able to be clicked again until the javascript is reloaded.
2. To make it infinitely nest-able with questions inside of questions inside of topics... you could just have a class like `.expandable` that is applied to a `<div>` that wraps around a header element and any subelements and any `<h#>` inside an `.expandable` div is a clickable title to show the next tier and hide itself.
3. You only need `$(document).ready(function () {...});` once wrapping all of the code you want to execute at document ready time.

Here's an example of the nest-able solution with links to go back up a level:

```
<div class="expandable top">
    <h1>Topic 1</h1>
    <div class="expandable">
        <h1>foo</h1>
        <div class="expandable">
            <h1>sub-foo</h1>
            <div class="expandable">
                Stuff
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="expandable">
        <h1>bar</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="expandable top">
    <h1>Topic 2</h1>
    <div class="expandable">
        <h1>foo2</h1>
        <div class="expandable">
            <h1>sub-foo2</h1>
            <div class="expandable">
                Stuff
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="expandable">
        <h1>bar2</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.expandable').hide().filter('.top').show(); //hide every expandable div except the top one
        $('.expandable h1').click(function () {
            $(this).hide(); //hides the header
            $(this).parent().siblings().hide(); //hide the whole tier
            //show the hidden siblings, then add a link to go back up
            $(this).siblings().show().last().after('<a href="#" class="up-link">Up one level</a>');
            //add a click handler to the new link to reverse what we've just done
            $(this).siblings('a.up-link').click(function () {
                $(this).siblings().hide().filter('h1').show();
                $(this).parent().siblings(':not(h1)').show();
                $(this).remove();
                return false; //prevent event propagation on the link so you don't navigate to #
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly. I think I've almost got it, but I'm missing something...:-). When I use the code you sent and click "Title" is hidden, but "foo" does not show. Also, I know how to add a button, but is there a way to do it so it looks like an underlined link that reads "Return to Topics"? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @user2316544 - Edited my answer to include a more robust example

Comment: I've updated my question with a couple of clarification questions. 
Can’t thank you enough. I’m really starting to see the difference between “playing” with jQuery and really “using” it.
 Really enjoyed (and kept laughing at as I typed, your all to accurate description of my original code, in your titles...:-)

Thanks again for you oh so patient help.

Comment: @user2316544 - Edited the script in my answer so that it accommodates your further clarification. Hopefully you're beginning to see how jQuery works and how to utilize jQuery's chain-able functions to traverse and manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Yes! Thanks to you I am. Feels like a crash course in a single block of code. The one thing I don't understand is how this first line of code shows both Topic 1 and Topic 2: $('.expandable').hide().filter('.top').show(); . When you say “it hides every expandable div except the top one”, do you mean the top level? It works perfectly. I just want to really understand why it does.

Comment: There are a couple of ways that could've been written but the way I did it goes like this: $('.expandable') selects the expandable class divs, then hide() hides them. The .filter('.top') refines the '.expandable's down to the ones that have .top class. Then I show() those (because I just hid them). Other ways could be to just use css to set .expandables to display:none, or as I demonstrated down in the 'up-link' handler, you can use the pseudo-selector ':not()' to filter ahead of time: $('.expandable:not(.top)').hide();

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks! One last question if you have the time. When you get down to what ever the lowest level is, is there a way to keep the last item from being clickable? Right now, if someone clicks on it, it will send them to a blank screen. Can't thank you enough for the help and true education.

Comment: Also, I don't see where you put this code that you just referred to: $('.expandable:not(.top)').hide(); . The only "not" I see is this: $(this).parent().siblings(':not(h1)').show();

Comment: I think I just figured out my first question. Is the best way to do this to change the tag on the element I don't want to be clickable (In you example, change the hl tags to h2 tags)? Still curious about the line of code I couldn't find.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my comment. I meant that in the .up-link click handler is an example of using the pseudo-selector :not(). Then I put an example of how you could use :not() for the hiding of all the expandables that is not in the answer. Just showing the flexibility of jQuery. As for making the deepest ones not clickable, yes changing to h2 tags (or any other, like <p>) will work, as it only looks for the 'h1' tags to make clickable.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Once again, can't thank you enough for the fastest "up to speed" education I've ever gotten.

Comment: @user2316544 - If this answer helped you solve your problem could I humbly ask that you accept the answer :) Thanks!

Comment: Happy to. Couldn't figure it out, but FINALLY did. Told you I was new...:-) Thanks again!

Comment: If you have the time. How would I adjust the code you recommended for the following scenario?

I have a 2 row table – the top row is a single column and the 2nd row is 3 columns. Each of the 4 “table cells” has one of the “expandable divs” from your example. I want to create the same effect, but hiding and showing the data in one cell instead of one item in a list

Your code works for the cells that are in the same row, but not if the there is more than one row. So if I click on the top row cell, the bottom row cells aren't hidden and vice versa.

Any help you can be would be great.

Comment: You have to think about how the DOM is organized to understand the way these traversing functions work. The .siblings() and .parent() will select different elements in different contexts. If the current jQuery selection is a td or td's, the siblings of the current element are the other cells in the row; the parent is the tr. Think of it this way: where do you want to go from where you are and what you want to do when you get there. Check out the API documentation for Traversing http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/, try some stuff, and then ask a new question if you're still stuck.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go play so more. I started going down the route I think you're suggesting, but couldn't figure out what a table row above a table row would be? Is that the parent of a parent? I tried posting a separate question, but the reply back I got was using the .html method which was so different I got stumped trying to get the two to work together. Which I why I came back to you...:-) I understand you're not answering directly is to help me learn to really understand this, but I'm really at a loss (even how to phrase the question), so even another hint or 2 would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: If you're starting with a td then its containing row is its .parent(). The neighboring tr's are the .siblings() of this parent tr. For example: $('td').parent().siblings()...; explanation: 1) get the td(s), 2) move up to the parent tr of said td(s), 3) get the other rows next to this one.

Comment: I'm going to figure this out if it kills me...:-) If I move up to the parent tr of the tds that will still only remove that one table row, so even if I were to set up a separate click event for top row, it still wouldn't effect the 2nd row, or vice versa. Do I need to nest the table rows within another table row to connect them or am I, once again, missing the obvious?...:-) That just doesn't sound right, but for some reason I just can't seem to see this. Thanks for you continued support and patience.

Comment: I think I've almost go it. I changed your line for hiding the whole tier (and showing it when you click the back button) to '$(this).parent().parent().siblings().hide();' which solves the "row" problem, but I'm missing how to write this so that it will hide the siblings, too. I also tried .closest(), but that didn't work. What was frustrating about the Transversing Documentation is that most of the things that sound right work for siblings, but since these aren't syblings, I couldn't figure out where to go. Then I got this part to partially work, so figured I'd check back before going further.

Comment: Forgot to mention my testing your earlier example. What I coulnd't figure out was how to move down to the next row. In other words, I can see how, as you put it, you "move up to the parent tr" (which helps when you click on the bottom row), but couldn't see how you move down when you click on the top row. Hoping any or all of this makes sense...:-)

Comment: I'm think we've abused the comment section on this answer enough :)  I'll take a look at your other question and see if I can come up with something that is more appropriate to the new structure you're talking about.